# Plupload conflict with moxiemanager (tinymce)

Tags: tinymce, plupload, moxiemanager

I have a problem with the work of plupload namely:
I have tinyMCE embedded on one page with the MoxieMannager plugin and I have Plupload on the same page (for uploading files).

So Plupload works, but if you activate Moxiemanager (on page), then everything stops working right away? How to bypass this restriction?

code sample:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="./plupload/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({ 
selector:'<?php print $MCE3; ?>',  
toolbar: "<?php print $MCE2; ?>",
language: 'ru',
plugins: '<?php print $MCE; ?>',  
relative_urls : true,
document_base_url : "<?php print $url; ?>"
   });</script>


<a data-action='uploadFile' class="ipsButton ipsButton_small ipsButton_primary ipsPos_left" id="pickfiles" href="javascript:;">Выбрать файл...1</a>
<a data-action='uploadFile' class="ipsButton ipsButton_small ipsButton_primary ipsPos_left" id="uploadfiles" href="javascript:;">Загрузить на сервер</a>

<ul id="filelist"></ul>
<pre id="console"></pre>
 

<script type="text/javascript">
// Custom example logic
var uploader3 = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',   
    browse_button : 'pickfiles', // you can pass in id...
    container: document.getElementById('container'), 
    url : "./plupload/examples/q1.php?pgid=<?php print $pgid; ?>",
    filters : {
  pgid: <?php print $pgid; ?>,
        max_file_size : '10mb',
        mime_types: [
            {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
            {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
        ]
    },
 
    // Flash settings
    flash_swf_url : '/plupload/Moxie.swf',
 
    // Silverlight settings
    silverlight_xap_url : '/plupload/Moxie.xap',       
    init: {
        PostInit: function() {
            document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';
 
            document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function() {
                uploader3.start();
      return false;    
            };
        },
 
        FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
            plupload.each(files, function(file) {
                document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></div>';
            });
        },
 
        UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
            document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
        },
 
        Error: function(up, err) {
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message;
        }
    }
 
});
uploader3.init();
</script>
```

Please help solve the problem

Comment: MoxieManager itself contains Plupload (at least contained), so maybe you do not need to include it second time. Recheck.